# Setting options of selenium driver but refuses connection-Python-Firefox (Please do not set duplicated before reading problem )

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am having some problems about assign a profile to selenium webdriver.I tried many options to achieve this now i am close it but this time there is an other error which i got.The code below achieved to assign the profile what i need but it opens firefox but refuses connection.

PS:It says duplicated or possible answer but not,I am not talking bout Phontom and I dont want to use phantom
Python 3.7
geckodriver 0.23
Firefox 63
selenium 3.14

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary 


fp = FirefoxProfile('C:\\Users\\<USER>\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\ta5ybndz.test')
binary=FirefoxBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
options.add_argument("-profile") 

options.add_argument("C:/Users/<USER>/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/ta5ybndz.test")

browser=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path,firefox_binary=binary,options=options)
```

This is the log file:

> 1541767559696 mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command:
> "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
> "-marionette" "-profile"
> "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\dnm8f0kz.default-1541758576709"
> "-foreground" "-no-remote" IPDL protocol error: Handler returned error
> code!
>
> #### !!! [Parent][DispatchAsyncMessage] Error: PLayerTransaction::Msg_ReleaseLayer Processing error: message was
>
> deserialized, but the handler returned false (indicating failure)
>
> IPDL protocol error: Handler returned error code!
>
> #### !!! [Parent][DispatchAsyncMessage] Error: PLayerTransaction::Msg_ReleaseLayer Processing error: message was
>
> deserialized, but the handler returned false (indicating failure)
>
> [Parent 10284, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file
> z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc,
> line 346 [Parent 10284, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file
> z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc,
> line 346 [Child 12268, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109:
> file
> z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc,
> line 346[ Child 3464, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109:
> file
> z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc,
> line 346 [Child 3464, C[Parent 10284, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe
> error: 109: file
> z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc,
> line 346 [Child 12132, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109:
> file
> z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc,
> line 346 [Child 1213
>
> #### !!! [Child][MessageChannel::SendAndWait] Error: Channel error: cannot send/recv
>
> 1541767610497 mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command:
> "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
> "-marionette" "-profile"
> "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\dnm8f0kz.default-1541758576709"
> "-foreground" "-no-remote"

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan  its not duplicated.Completely different!Can you remove duplicated sign please ?

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan did you read my problem ?